# android.app.Application cannot be cast to class extending android.app.Application

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have created a class that extends android.app.Application

However whenever I try to instantiate the class by:

```
AppExt appExt = (AppExt) this.getApplication();
```

throws the aforementioned error

Since it extends the android.app.Application class why would I encounter this error

Comment: Are you sure it's the same class? If I remember right, this class is also available in the support library.

Comment: Can you share exception stack trace please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your class in AndroidManifest:

```
<application
            android:name="your.package.AppExt"
```

Comment: How do I add multiple, as I am using it for my crash reports and want to now add it for google analytics?